# how to submit a value in master page using jquery modal confirmation box

Tags: jquery, asp.net

my problem is simple
1.iwill select a item in dropdown to delete

1. after selection i will click the delete button

3.immediately the jquerymodal confirmation box will appear with delete and cancel option

1. if i click the delete option thenonly the selected dropdown item should delete in ddl list as well as in database

   ```
            $(document).ready(function () {

               $("#<%=btndlt.ClientID%>").click(function (e){

                   if ($("#<%=ddlbus.ClientID%>").val() == "") {

                     e.preventDefault();

                     $("#jqselect").dialog();
                   }
                 else {



                     $("#jqdialog").dialog({
                         autoopen:false,
                         modal: true,
                         resizable: false,
                         draggable: false,
                         buttons: {
                             "Delete all items": function () {

     // problem is here how to delete the seleted item (ie) how to submit the master page form
                             },
                             Cancel: function () {
                                 $(this).dialog("close");
                                 return false;
                             }
                         }
                });

                   }

               });
          });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an option that is necessary for use with ASP.NET forms. You must set the dialog to append to the form. Pass the `appendTo: "form"` option in when you initialize the dialog. For more info, see [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/).